# svg hover animation fallback / create hover animate using snap.svg

Tags: css, animation, svg, hover, snap.svg

I am new to svg / svg animation.
I studied that it's better to have fallback for svg.
However, if I want to develop svg animation, it seems so hard for me to use .svg  instead of the whole path thing of svg input in html file (not sure what it called).
For example like this: http://codepen.io/rae0724/pen/Mbxwgj
I need the svg animate like this when I hover it.
But what if the user browser do not support svg?
How can I create the fallback? Or actually it's good to put like this?

If I am using the svg like below, it allow me to create fallback:

```
<img src="images/icon.svg" onerror="this.src='icon.png'; this.onerror=null;">
```

But I can't create animation with this.

Is it better to use snap.svg (which I got no idea how to use it at all) to create hover animation?
Anyone know how to to it with snap.svg?

Thank you.

Comment: img content is not interactive so there's no way to make its SVG content do anything on hover. You'd have to use another tag e,g, object or iframe.

Comment: i see, i studied that there is downside for object?